# Anime identification from an image with a bejeweled skeleton

Tags: story-identification, anime

I saw this on a YouTube video and was trying to figure out which anime this is from.

[image: YouTube screenshot]

Answer (score 18):

This character is [Armonia Justin Beyondormason](http://deathnote.wikia.com/wiki/Armonia_Justin_Beyondormason), one of several [shinigami](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shinigami) from the anime and manga series [Death Note](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Death_Note). While a few shinigami are major characters in the series, interfering in the world of humans, Armonia only appears in a handful of scenes taking place in the shinigami's own world.

His golden, jeweled appearance in the anime is based directly on his appearance in the original manga, in which he is only depicted in black-and-white art but is still notable for his jewel-encrusted appearance:

[image]

Answer (score 13):

Heres what "I" found, but not sure about the accurate answer though

This is the video entitled “Death Note- Blinged out Shinigami”.

Comment: Is this video some separate standalone or is this video just an excerpt from the anime Death Note?

Comment: Not sure, But I think it is from Death note because they are characters from it?

Comment: I'm just saying, unless you can confirm that this character doesn't appear in the anime proper but only in this video, I think the answer could be improved by restating it to say that the answer is "Death Note" rather than making it sound like it's originally from this youtube video. Linking the video is still fine as evidence of how you discovered the answer, but it looks like the answer is "Death Note" rather than this youtube video.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: if you look at the [deathnote wiki](http://deathnote.wikia.com/wiki/Shinigami), you can see this Shinigami in the center of the [first picture](https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/deathnote/images/0/00/Death-note-shinigami-mural-rem-ryuk-gelus-sidoh-wallpaper.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20110528011906)

Comment: I have a good suggestion for you if you want, is that in the future if you find any pictures like this, try reverse google pictures.